# Lock a specific version of a third party package in Go

Tags: go, module

Using modules, when I try to lock down a specific version of a package using the following command:

```
go mod edit -require "google.golang.org/grpc@v1.10.0"
```

It shows this under the `require` section in the `go.mod` file:

```
google.golang.org/protobuf v1.10.0
```

And then when I run:

```
go mod vendor
```

It is always pulling down the latest version which is currently `v1.24.0`. Under the `require` section in the `go.mod` file it shows:

```
google.golang.org/protobuf v1.24.0
```

Is there a way to lock a specific version no matter what?

I am currently using go version 1.14.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is possible to tell go mod to only get the versions specified without bumping the version.

```
go -mod=readonly mod vendor
```

Can be found at: https://github.com/thepudds/go-module-knobs/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I guess this does not work anymore: `flag provided but not defined: -mod`

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this problem is do `go build` once you have made specific changes to go mod file. This will ensure you have `go.sum` file built into your codebase. This is nothing but checksum of your fetched package. By doing this, all the future pull will match the checksum of go.sum file